# Why didn't Doctor Strange wind back the clock way before Thanos got any of the Infinity Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, doctor-strange

Why didn't Doctor Strange wind back the clock way before Thanos got any of the Infinity Stones?

Comment: Clearly he was unable to wind back the entire universe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it was not a winning scenario. In *Avengers: Infinity War* we see Doctor Strange look into the future to see outcomes of the possible conflicts and saying they only win one. Considering the amount of possibilities he looks at it is highly likely at least one involved rewinding time.

> **Doctor Strange:** *[panting]* I went forward in time to view alternate futures. To see all the possible outcomes of the coming conflict.
>
> **Peter Quill:** How many did you see?
>
> **Doctor Strange:** 14,000,605.
>
> **Tony Stark:** How many did we win?
>
> *[Strange stares intently at Tony for a moment]*
>
> **Strange:** *[pause]* One.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

At the end of the film Strange then comments to Tony the following:

> **Doctor Strange:** *[calmly turns to Stark]* Tony, there was no other way.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Adding both of these together we see that the outcome at the end of *Infinity War* was the only solution Strange saw for beating Thanos.

It's also not known how much power Doctor Strange can harness from the Time Stone and so it isn't known if he could wind time back for the entire universe.

Comment: He only went forward in time to see different scenarios, not the past

Comment: @Mocas And? His actions to reverse time must be in the future so looking forward he would see where he reversed time.

Comment: Is there a limit to how much he can wind back time? Like in Dr Strange... he activated the stone, 'fought' Dormamu, and it kept resetting to that point everytime he lost?

Comment: @Kwola-T Perhaps there he was aided a bit by Dormamu's default nature of being outside of our normal flow of time. It didn't remotely make sense, but in the temporo/mysticobabble explanation at the end of the *Dr. Strange* movie, I recall there being something about how the loop was Strange imposing our type of time on Dormamu, who wasn't accustomed to such a flow. Trying to logically reason from events in the *Dr. Strange* movie is difficult in general, given how hand-wavy it was.